# ext.msg.alert not working

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs 2.0.1, I have some buttons on which I either do form.submit or Ext.Ajax.request. on success of above request, I read the response and depending upon response I need to show a pop-up/alert to uer. Problem is ext.msg.alert , ext.msg.show nothing seems to be working in this case. but if I use simplet alert() it works fine. This is very strange because I have used ext.msg.alert  many times I did not face any issue till now. Can anyone help me to figure out the issue?
code is

```
 fp.getForm().submit( {
        url : some url
        method :'POST',
        waitMsg :'please wait',
        success :function(response,status) {
             var dataResponse = Ext.util.JSON.decode(status.response.responseText);
             var warning=dataResponse['warning'];
             if(warning != "false"){                    
                Ext.Msg.alert("Warning!",warning);//NOT WORKING
                alert(warning); //WORKS FINE
             }
             var tab = tabs2.getComponent(2);
             var tabs2Panel = tabs2.setActiveTab(tab);
             },
```

Comment: Just a small check, have you included the MessageBox class in your page?

Comment: yes, Ext.Msg.alert is working in same class in case of failure scenario of the form submit.... but its not working in success..

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Msg.alert is not modal dialog, you have to use a callback function invoked after the message box is closed. Code must be rewritten like this

```
fp.getForm().submit( {
        url : some url
        method :'POST',
        waitMsg :'please wait',
        success :function(response,status) {
             var dataResponse = Ext.util.JSON.decode(status.response.responseText);
             var warning=dataResponse['warning'];
             if(warning != "false"){                    
                Ext.Msg.alert("Warning!",warning, function() {
                    alert(warning);
                    var tab = tabs2.getComponent(2);
                    var tabs2Panel = tabs2.setActiveTab(tab);
                });                
             }
         },
```